# Number of rows R check to determine the number format through ODBC connection

Tags: r, odbc, rodbc

I am reading a large csv file in R around 2 gb. The data read is successful. The issue is that while while checking the data in the View mode I found that the fraction part of many number format column is truncated. I am able to figure out the issue is that R is scanning first few rows to determine the number format for that row.

So do anyone have any idea to set that number of rows to scan to set the number format. I also tried the command 'as.is' in R, but no success.

In SAS we can do it using the command "guessingrows" in proc import. Is there there is any such command in R?

Thanks,
Sumanta

---

Hi,

I am attaching the below screenshot of the data in csv format opened in excel and after importing in R.

[CSV screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFQgU.png)
The row number is 2175. Here numbers are present after decimal. Check the figures highlighted in RED box.

[R import screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGGOQ.png)
In excel preview we can see the decimal part but not in R after import.

Note that, here I am importing the csv through ODBC, because I can run query through ODBC on the CSV file and this helps to import only the required summary output. That is, there is no need to import the whole 2GB csv file in the memory and this can save resources.

```
> library(RODBC)
> con <- odbcConnect("CSV Data") # Here "CSV Data" is the connection created in the ODBC Data Source in control Panel. It is saving the path to CSV files which will act as a database location for R.
> qry <- "select * from 2013.csv"
> data <- sqlQuery(con,qry)
> odbcCloseAll()
```

But when I directly using the read.csv to import the file, I got the correct output. See the screenshot.[Correct Output in R using read.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ5oV.png)

```
> data1 <- read.csv(file = "----file path----\\2013.csv")
```

The issue is that I can't use read.csv as it will take 2GB memory space to store the csv file. So I am using the RODBC method.

Regards,

Sumanta

Comment: What do you mean by *truncated*?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the viewing? Pull some numbers individually in your interactive window and see how they look there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not check your data using the *View mode*, [as Sotos kinda allude to above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840946/number-of-rows-r-check-to-determine-the-number-format#comment84686027_48840946).

I don't know what your data look like -- you should by the way strive to provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question -- so I'll make a very simple example. It can be update to look more like your data.

First I import some dummy csv,

```
foobar <- read.csv(text="foo,bar, cat\n1, 2, Korat\n.000000000000000001,3, Balinese")
```

Now, I would start by investigating the imported structure, `foobar`, using `str()`, i.e.,

```
str(foobar)
#> 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ foo: num  1e+00 1e-18
#>  $ bar: int  2 3
#>  $ cat: Factor w/ 2 levels " Balinese"," Korat": 2 1
```

Here you can see that this data is one numeric, `num`, vector, one integer, `int`, and one factor, `Factor` all wrapped up a data frame consisting of 3 variables and 2 observations.

Next I would use `summary()`

```
summary(foobar)
#>       foo            bar              cat   
#>  Min.   :0.00   Min.   :2.00    Balinese:1  
#>  1st Qu.:0.25   1st Qu.:2.25    Korat   :1  
#>  Median :0.50   Median :2.50                
#>  Mean   :0.50   Mean   :2.50                
#>  3rd Qu.:0.75   3rd Qu.:2.75                
#>  Max.   :1.00   Max.   :3.00
```

Finally, you can expect single elements like this

```
foobar[2,c('foo')]
#> [1] 1e-18
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I have added some screenshot of the file. Kindly check. Hope this time the problem statement is clear.

Answer (score 0):

At last after investigating a lot I am successfully solved the issue myself. Thus want to share the solution.

After creating the ODBC connection (from "ODBC Data Source Administrator" in Control Panel), select "configure". In the window "ODBC Text Setup" click on "options". Now click on "Define Format...". In the new window "Define Text Format" select the files you are concerned with and then set the "Rows to Scan" to ZERO. By default it is set to 25. Select all the databases one-by-one and set the value to 0. The ZERO indicates the full data scan to set the length of characters for a particular column.

Also make tick mark on "Column Name Header", this will detect the headers automatically.

Attached is the screenshot.["Define Text Format" Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75jrK.png)

Thanks and Regards,

Sumanta